# Android java enum fails on one line

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm trying to declare a lot of enums however for some reason one of them is erroring and I can't really see why.

My declaration:

```
public class Enums {

    public enum MainObjectType {
        Plan = 0
                StationEntrance = 1
                StationConcourse_Hall = 2
                StationPlatform = 3
                StationStairs = 4
                StationEscalator = 5
                StationLift = 6
                StationRamp = 7
                StationSubway = 8
                StationTicket_Gates = 9
                StationOther = 12
                StationCar_Park = 13
                StationToilets = 14
                StationDoors = 15
                StationTravelator = 16
                StationLevel = 17
                StationMulti_stairs = 19
                StationSupervisor = 20
                StationInformation_Stand = 24
                StationTicket_Office = 28
                StationTravel_Info_Office = 30
                StationBabyChange = 50
                StationAccessibleToilets = 57
                StationTicket_Counter = 58
                StationDropOffPoint = 59
                StationStartPoint = 60
                StationToiletArea = 61

                StationTaxi = 250
                StationTaxiDropOffPoint = 259

                CarPark = 501
                Circulation = 502
                Internal_Doors = 503
                Surfaces = 504
                Toilets = 505
                Seating = 506
                Counters_Service_Desks = 507
                Telephones = 508
                Signage = 509
                Lighting = 510

                Acoustics = 511
                Drop_off = 513
                Routes = 514
                Reception = 515
                Consultation_area = 516
                Creche = 518
                Means_of_escape = 519
                Ramp = 523
                Steps = 524
                PassengerLift = 525
                PlatformLift = 526
                SwimmingPool = 527
                ChangingRoom = 528
                VendingMachine = 529
                CashMachine = 530
                Entrance = 531
                Room = 532
                AccessibleWC = 533
                Consultation_Room = 535
                TransportTypes = 536
                Escalator = 537
                Intercomm = 538
                Other = 539
                CorridorRoom = 540
                Approach = 586
                WheelChairStairLift = 587
                MultiRamp = 588
                BusStands = 591
                BusStop = 592
                Level = 594
                FloorPlan = 1001
                WayPoint = 1003
                RoutingArrow = 1004
                Poster = 1005
                GlobalArea = 1007

                ManagersQuestions = 2000
                Knowledgebase = 2001
                SeatingBlock = 2002

                FireExtinguisher = 2006

                HS_StatutoryComplianceDocs = 3003
                HS_WorkplaceQuestions = 3004
                HS_Findings = 3005
                HS_Verification = 3006
                HS_Assessor_Notes = 3008

                FR_Limitations = 3001
                FR_PolicyReview = 3002
                FR_Verification = 3021
                FR_Findings = 3022
                FR_Policies = 3024
                FR_AlarmSystem = 3056
                FR_Assessor_Notes = 3007

                GEN_BuildingQuestions = 3023


                NPM_PolicyReview = 3550
                NPM_ManagerQuestions = 3552
                NPM_Policies = 3551
                NPM_Verification = 3553

                NPM_Findings = 3554
                NPM_Assessor_Notes = 3555
                AssetItem = 3200


                FR_MajorIssues = 3562
                HS_MajorIssues = 3563
                NPM_MajorIssues = 3564
    }


}
```

The error says: Syntax error, insert } to complete classbody

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You syntax is not valid. You can write:

```
public enum MainObjectType  {
    StationEntrance,
    StationConcourse_Hall,
    StationPlatform,
    StationStairs,
    // ...
    NPM_MajorIssues;        
}
```

But that would lose the numbering. Or you could provide a number with the following syntax:

```
public enum MainObjectType  {
    StationEntrance(1),
    StationConcourse_Hall(2),
    StationPlatform(3),
    StationStairs(4),
    // ...
    NPM_MajorIssues(3564);        

    private final int id;
    private MainObjectType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

You can then write:

```
int id = MainObjectType.StationEntrance.getId(); //id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The elements of the enum need to be separated by commas and your syntax for setting the value of each element is incorrect.

First, you need to use the proper syntax for setting the value. The syntax should be `EnumValue(value)` where you have a private constructor that takes the type that you are setting the enum element to. In this case, you need a `private MainObjectType(int value)` constructor in your enum. You also need to delimit each element with a comma.

Check out [the Java tutorial for enum types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for some examples.